# SQL Developer oracle 00904 "MAY" invalid identifier- can't solve

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get count of the values between the dates of the two columns with the following:

```
 select count (DISTINCT GNO) 
 from BOOKING
 where DATEFROM > 31/MAR/97 and DATETO < 01/MAY/97;
```

And I keep getting

> the 00904 error "MAY" being an invalid identifier.

Also the date groups are `Date` data types. I can't figure it out as the schema takes input values in the date group format described above with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select count (DISTINCT GNO) 
from BOOKING
where DATEFROM > to_date( '31/MAR/97', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' ) and DATETO < to_date( '01/MAY/97', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing single quotes around the date literals, `31/MAR/97` -> `'31/MAR/97'`.